# Python Function Execution - Requested for Clarifications

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote a below code by looking at some websites and with my knowledge and while it comes to output I have few queries:

`factorial (3)` will pass argument as `n=3` to function, where `n` value not equal to zero it should reach to `else` part of the program and execute my code. In else part

Here I am confused, why it’s printing `1` as first output and followed by other values?

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        recurse = factorial(n-1)
        result = n * recurse
    print result
    return result
```

Output:

```
>>> factorial(3)
1
2
6
6
```

Comment: Your function is indeed confusing, you probably want `result = 1` instead of `return 1` on line 3.

Answer (score 0):

The `else` branch calls a recursive function *first*; those recursive calls also use `print`.

```
factorial(3)
    n = 3 -> else
    recurse = factorial(n - 1)
        n = 2 -> else
        recurse = factorial(n - 1)
            n = 1 -> else
            recurse = factorial(n - 1)
                n = 0 -> if
                return 1
            result = n * recurse -> 1 * 1
            print 1
            return 1
        result = n * recurse -> 2 * 1
        print 2
        return 2
    result = n * recurse -> 3 * 2
    print 6
    return 6
```

Note the order of the `print` calls; once you hit `n == 0` the recursive functions start returning and you reach a `print` statement, followed by another `return` and another `print`, etc.

Comment: Martijn: Can you please elobrate more about your comment.. am new to python and programming as well...

Comment: factorial(3) -> n = 3 -> else
    recurse = factorial(n - 1) -> n = 2 -> else
        recurse = factorial(n - 1) -> n = 1 -> else
            recurse = factorial(n - 1) -> n = 0 -> if
                return 1
            result = n * recurse -> 1 * 1
            print 1
            return 1
        result = n * recurse -> 2 * 1
        print 2
        return 2
    result = n * recurse -> 3 * 2
    print 6
    return 6


How come result value changed to 2 in (result = n * recurse -> 2 * 1)?

Comment: @SivaKrishna: because in that function the value for `n` is still 2. Locals are not shared between function calls.